# How to get Clion to work on Ubuntu 20.04 xrdp?

Tags: 20.04, xrdp

I installed xrdp and already it was not working out of the box. I had to apply following two fixes. [Fix 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417906/authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile), used the answer by Nemo and [fix 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193810/authentication-required-to-refresh-system-repositories-in-ubuntu-19-10), used the answer by DeepSpace101.
Now I get to problem 3. Namely I want to start Clion from the console using `nohup clion &` and I get following error: `Cannot find VM options file` I know that this is a problem related to xrdp, because locally this command works. While we're at it, I also don't have a dashboard or the favorites bar on the left. How can I get xrdp to work(clion issue) and to look(dashboard, favorites bar) like when I log locally into Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

@Hakaishin

**To solve your Desktop look'n feel while connected through xRDP**

xRDP can be used in conjunction with Ubuntu (Gnome Desktop) and present you the same Desktop look'n feel but you have to perform some post configuration actions if you have installed xrdp manually

To have the Ubuntu gnome desktop with dock bar presented to you, you can

**Option 1 - Manual Fix**

Try to create and populate the file ~/.xsessionrc with the following content

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Please note that the .xsessionrc file is a hidden file (located in your home directory)

This would be for a single user. If multiple users need to perform remote connection, each user would need to have this file created in their profile

**Option 2 - Automated install**

You can also use the xrdp-installer script that basically perform the installation of the software and perform some post configuration actions that would provide you the same look'n feel when remotely connected as the one you have when connected to local console

the script (current version is 1.2.1) and how to use it can be found [here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733)

Please always check for the latest version of the script at [this location](https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html)

Hope this help

Till next time

See ya